# What happens if my auction listing ends with no bids placed?

Tags: ebay

Specifically, do I have to pay some sort of fee if that happens?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer.

It mainly depends on the product you auction, the type of auction and your account type.
Basically, your final fees come in the form of **Insertion fees** and **Percentage fees**

> When you list and sell items on eBay, we charge selling fees. There
> are two main types of selling fees: **an insertion fee when you create
> a listing**, and a **final value fee *when your item sells***.
>
> The amount we charge depends on the item's price, the format and
> category you choose for your listing, any optional listing upgrades
> you add, and your seller conduct and performance.

You should **carefully read** the pages about [Selling through auctions](https://www.ebay.com/help/selling/listings/selling-auctions?id=4110), [Selling fees](https://www.ebay.com/help/selling/fees-credits-invoices/selling-fees?id=4364#section2), [Ending a listing](https://www.ebay.com/help/selling/listings/creating-managing-listings/ending-listing?id=4146) and [Store selling fees](https://www.ebay.com/help/selling/selling-fees/store-fees?id=4122)

Comment: Have you followed the given solution? Did it work for you? If not please add what is missing. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.